# LinkedIn API - Setting user status saying unauthorised

Tags: json, api, linkedin-api, status

So I've been following through various tutorials and documents to get this working and am really struggling. These are the files required for it to work:

## Required Files

#### auth.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $config['base_url']             =   '';
    $config['callback_url']         =   '';
    $config['linkedin_access']      =   '';
    $config['linkedin_secret']      =   '';

    include_once "linkedin.php";

    # The first step is to initialize with your consumer key and secret. We'll use an out-of-band oauth_callback.
    $linkedin = new LinkedIn($config['linkedin_access'], $config['linkedin_secret'], $config['callback_url'] );
    //$linkedin->debug = true;

    # Now we retrieve a request token. It will be set as $linkedin->request_token.
    $linkedin->getRequestToken();
    $_SESSION['requestToken'] = serialize($linkedin->request_token);

    # With a request token in hand, we can generate an authorization URL, which we'll direct the user to.
    //echo "Authorization URL: " . $linkedin->generateAuthorizeUrl() . "\n\n";
    header("Location: " . $linkedin->generateAuthorizeUrl()); ?>
```

#### demo.php

This is the script that I get after signup:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $config['base_url']             =   'http://xxx/linkedin/auth.php';
    $config['callback_url']         =   'http://xxx/linkedin/demo.php';
    $config['linkedin_access']      =   '';
    $config['linkedin_secret']      =   '';

    include_once "linkedin.php";

    # The first step is to initialize with your consumer key and secret. We'll use an out-of-band oauth_callback.
    $linkedin = new LinkedIn($config['linkedin_access'], $config['linkedin_secret'], $config['callback_url'] );

    //$linkedin->debug = true; if (isset($_REQUEST['oauth_verifier'])){

        $_SESSION['oauth_verifier']     = $_REQUEST['oauth_verifier'];

        $linkedin->request_token    =   unserialize($_SESSION['requestToken']);
        $linkedin->oauth_verifier   =   $_SESSION['oauth_verifier'];
        $linkedin->getAccessToken($_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']);

        $_SESSION['oauth_access_token'] = serialize($linkedin->access_token);
        header("Location: " . $config['callback_url']);
        exit;}   else{
        $linkedin->request_token    =   unserialize($_SESSION['requestToken']);
        $linkedin->oauth_verifier   =   $_SESSION['oauth_verifier'];
        $linkedin->access_token     =   unserialize($_SESSION['oauth_access_token']);}

    # You now have a $linkedin->access_token and can make calls on behalf of the current member.
    $xml_response = $linkedin->getProfile("~:(id,first-name,last-name,headline,picture-url)");

    $id = $linkedin->getProfile('~:(id)');
    $fname = $linkedin->getProfile('~:(first-name)');
    $lname = $linkedin->getProfile('~:(last-name)');
    $headline = $linkedin->getProfile('~:(headline)');
    $picture = $linkedin->getProfile('~:(picture-url)');

    $id = trim(strip_tags($id));
    $fname = trim(strip_tags($fname));
    $lname = trim(strip_tags($lname));
    $headline = trim(strip_tags($headline));
    $picture = trim(strip_tags($picture)); ?>
```

linkedin.php

This is linkedin library:

```
<?php require_once("OAuth.php"); class LinkedIn {
    public $base_url = "http://api.linkedin.com";
    public $secure_base_url = "https://api.linkedin.com";
    public $oauth_callback = "oob";
    public $consumer;
    public $request_token;
    public $access_token;
    public $oauth_verifier;
    public $signature_method;
    public $request_token_path;
    public $access_token_path;
    public $authorize_path;

    function __construct($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $oauth_callback = NULL)
    {
        if($oauth_callback) {
            $this->oauth_callback = $oauth_callback;
        }

        $this->consumer = new OAuthConsumer($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $this->oauth_callback);
        $this->signature_method = new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1();
        $this->request_token_path = $this->secure_base_url . "/uas/oauth/requestToken";
        $this->access_token_path = $this->secure_base_url . "/uas/oauth/accessToken";
        $this->authorize_path = $this->secure_base_url . "/uas/oauth/authorize";
    }

    function getRequestToken()
    {
        $consumer = $this->consumer;
        $request = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($consumer, NULL, "GET", $this->request_token_path);
        $request->set_parameter("oauth_callback", $this->oauth_callback);
        $request->sign_request($this->signature_method, $consumer, NULL);
        $headers = Array();
        $url = $request->to_url();
        $response = $this->httpRequest($url, $headers, "GET");
        parse_str($response, $response_params);
        $this->request_token = new OAuthConsumer($response_params['oauth_token'], $response_params['oauth_token_secret'], 1);
    }

    function generateAuthorizeUrl()
    {
        $consumer = $this->consumer;
        $request_token = $this->request_token;
        return $this->authorize_path . "?oauth_token=" . $request_token->key;
    }

    function getAccessToken($oauth_verifier)
    {
        $request = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($this->consumer, $this->request_token, "GET", $this->access_token_path);
        $request->set_parameter("oauth_verifier", $oauth_verifier);
        $request->sign_request($this->signature_method, $this->consumer, $this->request_token);
        $headers = Array();
        $url = $request->to_url();
        $response = $this->httpRequest($url, $headers, "GET");
        parse_str($response, $response_params);
        $this->access_token = new OAuthConsumer($response_params['oauth_token'], $response_params['oauth_token_secret'], 1);
    }

    function getProfile($resource = "~")
    {
        $profile_url = $this->base_url . "/v1/people/" . $resource;
        $request = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($this->consumer, $this->access_token, "GET", $profile_url);
        $request->sign_request($this->signature_method, $this->consumer, $this->access_token);
        $auth_header = $request->to_header("https://api.linkedin.com"); # this is the realm
        # This PHP library doesn't generate the header correctly when a realm is not specified.
        # Make sure there is a space and not a comma after OAuth
        // $auth_header = preg_replace("/Authorization\: OAuth\,/", "Authorization: OAuth ", $auth_header);
        // # Make sure there is a space between OAuth attribute
        // $auth_header = preg_replace('/\"\,/', '", ', $auth_header);

        // $response will now hold the XML document
        $response = $this->httpRequest($profile_url, $auth_header, "GET");
        return $response;
    }

    function setStatus($status)
    {
        $profile_url = $this->base_url . "/v1/people/~";
        $status_url = $this->base_url . "/v1/people/~/current-status";
        echo "Setting status...\n";
        $xml = "<current-status>" . htmlspecialchars($status, ENT_NOQUOTES, "UTF-8") . "</current-status>";
        echo $xml . "\n";
        $request = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($this->consumer, $this->access_token, "PUT", $status_url);
        $request->sign_request($this->signature_method, $this->consumer, $this->access_token);
        $auth_header = $request->to_header("https://api.linkedin.com");

        $response = $this->httpRequest($profile_url, $auth_header, "GET");
        return $response;
    }

    # Parameters should be a query string starting with "?"
    # Example search("?count=10&start=10&company=LinkedIn");
    function search($parameters)
    {
        $search_url = $this->base_url . "/v1/people-search:(people:(id,first-name,last-name,picture-url,site-standard-profile-request,headline),num-results)" . $parameters;
        //$search_url = $this->base_url . "/v1/people-search?keywords=facebook";

        echo "Performing search for: " . $parameters . "<br />";
        echo "Search URL: $search_url <br />";
        $request = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($this->consumer, $this->access_token, "GET", $search_url);
        $request->sign_request($this->signature_method, $this->consumer, $this->access_token);
        $auth_header = $request->to_header("https://api.linkedin.com");
        $response = $this->httpRequest($search_url, $auth_header, "GET");
        return $response;
    }

    function httpRequest($url, $auth_header, $method, $body = NULL)
    {
        if (!$method) {
            $method = "GET";
        };

        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($auth_header)); // Set the headers.

        if ($body) {
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($auth_header, "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8"));
        }

        $data = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        return $data;
    }}
```

## The Problem

## Trying to set the status

To set the status update I have tried using this in the demo.php file:

```
$setStatus = "Testing API";
$statusResponse = $linkedin->setStatus("~:($setStatus)");
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($statusResponse);
echo '</pre>';
```

But it is giving me this error:

```
Setting status... ~:(Testing API)
string(343) "

401
1407931633217
DW74ALZZVN
0
[unauthorized]. OAU:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxxxxxx|*01|*01:1407931633:eyA6PiJzKUJixQLLtaQL90wppHI=

"
```

P.S: I x'd out the key there, but they are correct and the rest of the script works with them.

How do I set the status of the authorised account? So I've been following through various tutorials and documents to get this working and am really struggling. These are the files required for it to work:

## Required Files

#### auth.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $config['base_url']             =   '';
    $config['callback_url']         =   '';
    $config['linkedin_access']      =   '';
    $config['linkedin_secret']      =   '';

    include_once "linkedin.php";

    # The first step is to initialize with your consumer key and secret. We'll use an out-of-band oauth_callback.
    $linkedin = new LinkedIn($config['linkedin_access'], $config['linkedin_secret'], $config['callback_url'] );
    //$linkedin->debug = true;

    # Now we retrieve a request token. It will be set as $linkedin->request_token.
    $linkedin->getRequestToken();
    $_SESSION['requestToken'] = serialize($linkedin->request_token);

    # With a request token in hand, we can generate an authorization URL, which we'll direct the user to.
    //echo "Authorization URL: " . $linkedin->generateAuthorizeUrl() . "\n\n";
    header("Location: " . $linkedin->generateAuthorizeUrl()); ?>
```

#### demo.php

This is the script that I get after signup:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $config['base_url']             =   'http://xxx/linkedin/auth.php';
    $config['callback_url']         =   'http://xxx/linkedin/demo.php';
    $config['linkedin_access']      =   '';
    $config['linkedin_secret']      =   '';

    include_once "linkedin.php";

    # The first step is to initialize with your consumer key and secret. We'll use an out-of-band oauth_callback.
    $linkedin = new LinkedIn($config['linkedin_access'], $config['linkedin_secret'], $config['callback_url'] );

    //$linkedin->debug = true; if (isset($_REQUEST['oauth_verifier'])){

        $_SESSION['oauth_verifier']     = $_REQUEST['oauth_verifier'];

        $linkedin->request_token    =   unserialize($_SESSION['requestToken']);
        $linkedin->oauth_verifier   =   $_SESSION['oauth_verifier'];
        $linkedin->getAccessToken($_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']);

        $_SESSION['oauth_access_token'] = serialize($linkedin->access_token);
        header("Location: " . $config['callback_url']);
        exit;}   else{
        $linkedin->request_token    =   unserialize($_SESSION['requestToken']);
        $linkedin->oauth_verifier   =   $_SESSION['oauth_verifier'];
        $linkedin->access_token     =   unserialize($_SESSION['oauth_access_token']);}

    # You now have a $linkedin->access_token and can make calls on behalf of the current member.
    $xml_response = $linkedin->getProfile("~:(id,first-name,last-name,headline,picture-url)");


    $id = $linkedin->getProfile('~:(id)');
    $fname = $linkedin->getProfile('~:(first-name)');
    $lname = $linkedin->getProfile('~:(last-name)');
    $headline = $linkedin->getProfile('~:(headline)');
    $picture = $linkedin->getProfile('~:(picture-url)');

    $id = trim(strip_tags($id));
    $fname = trim(strip_tags($fname));
    $lname = trim(strip_tags($lname));
    $headline = trim(strip_tags($headline));
    $picture = trim(strip_tags($picture)); ?>
```

linkedin.php

This is linkedin library:

```
<?php require_once("OAuth.php"); class LinkedIn {
    public $base_url = "http://api.linkedin.com";
    public $secure_base_url = "https://api.linkedin.com";
    public $oauth_callback = "oob";
    public $consumer;
    public $request_token;
    public $access_token;
    public $oauth_verifier;
    public $signature_method;
    public $request_token_path;
    public $access_token_path;
    public $authorize_path;

    function __construct($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $oauth_callback = NULL)
    {
        if($oauth_callback) {
            $this->oauth_callback = $oauth_callback;
        }

        $this->consumer = new OAuthConsumer($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $this->oauth_callback);
        $this->signature_method = new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1();
        $this->request_token_path = $this->secure_base_url . "/uas/oauth/requestToken";
        $this->access_token_path = $this->secure_base_url . "/uas/oauth/accessToken";
        $this->authorize_path = $this->secure_base_url . "/uas/oauth/authorize";
    }

    function getRequestToken()
    {
        $consumer = $this->consumer;
        $request = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($consumer, NULL, "GET", $this->request_token_path);
        $request->set_parameter("oauth_callback", $this->oauth_callback);
        $request->sign_request($this->signature_method, $consumer, NULL);
        $headers = Array();
        $url = $request->to_url();
        $response = $this->httpRequest($url, $headers, "GET");
        parse_str($response, $response_params);
        $this->request_token = new OAuthConsumer($response_params['oauth_token'], $response_params['oauth_token_secret'], 1);
    }

    function generateAuthorizeUrl()
    {
        $consumer = $this->consumer;
        $request_token = $this->request_token;
        return $this->authorize_path . "?oauth_token=" . $request_token->key;
    }

    function getAccessToken($oauth_verifier)
    {
        $request = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($this->consumer, $this->request_token, "GET", $this->access_token_path);
        $request->set_parameter("oauth_verifier", $oauth_verifier);
        $request->sign_request($this->signature_method, $this->consumer, $this->request_token);
        $headers = Array();
        $url = $request->to_url();
        $response = $this->httpRequest($url, $headers, "GET");
        parse_str($response, $response_params);
        $this->access_token = new OAuthConsumer($response_params['oauth_token'], $response_params['oauth_token_secret'], 1);
    }

    function getProfile($resource = "~")
    {
        $profile_url = $this->base_url . "/v1/people/" . $resource;
        $request = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($this->consumer, $this->access_token, "GET", $profile_url);
        $request->sign_request($this->signature_method, $this->consumer, $this->access_token);
        $auth_header = $request->to_header("https://api.linkedin.com"); # this is the realm
        # This PHP library doesn't generate the header correctly when a realm is not specified.
        # Make sure there is a space and not a comma after OAuth
        // $auth_header = preg_replace("/Authorization\: OAuth\,/", "Authorization: OAuth ", $auth_header);
        // # Make sure there is a space between OAuth attribute
        // $auth_header = preg_replace('/\"\,/', '", ', $auth_header);

        // $response will now hold the XML document
        $response = $this->httpRequest($profile_url, $auth_header, "GET");
        return $response;
    }

    function setStatus($status)
    {
        $profile_url = $this->base_url . "/v1/people/~";
        $status_url = $this->base_url . "/v1/people/~/current-status";
        echo "Setting status...\n";
        $xml = "<current-status>" . htmlspecialchars($status, ENT_NOQUOTES, "UTF-8") . "</current-status>";
        echo $xml . "\n";
        $request = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($this->consumer, $this->access_token, "PUT", $status_url);
        $request->sign_request($this->signature_method, $this->consumer, $this->access_token);
        $auth_header = $request->to_header("https://api.linkedin.com");

        $response = $this->httpRequest($profile_url, $auth_header, "GET");
        return $response;
    }

    # Parameters should be a query string starting with "?"
    # Example search("?count=10&start=10&company=LinkedIn");
    function search($parameters)
    {
        $search_url = $this->base_url . "/v1/people-search:(people:(id,first-name,last-name,picture-url,site-standard-profile-request,headline),num-results)" . $parameters;
        //$search_url = $this->base_url . "/v1/people-search?keywords=facebook";

        echo "Performing search for: " . $parameters . "<br />";
        echo "Search URL: $search_url <br />";
        $request = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($this->consumer, $this->access_token, "GET", $search_url);
        $request->sign_request($this->signature_method, $this->consumer, $this->access_token);
        $auth_header = $request->to_header("https://api.linkedin.com");
        $response = $this->httpRequest($search_url, $auth_header, "GET");
        return $response;
    }

    function httpRequest($url, $auth_header, $method, $body = NULL)
    {
        if (!$method) {
            $method = "GET";
        };

        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($auth_header)); // Set the headers.

        if ($body) {
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($auth_header, "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8"));
        }

        $data = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        return $data;
    }}
```

## The Problem

## Trying to set the staus

To set the status update I have tried using this in the demo.php:

```
    $setStatus = "Testing API";
    $statusResponse = $linkedin->setStatus("~:($setStatus)");
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($statusResponse);
    echo '</pre>';
```

But it is giving me this error:

```
 Setting status... ~:(Testing API)
 string(343) "

 401
 1407931633217
 DW74ALZZVN
 0
 [unauthorized]. OAU:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxxxxxx|*01|*01:1407931633:eyA6PiJzKUJixQLLtaQL90wppHI=

"
```

P.S: I x'd out the key there, but they are correct and the rest of the script works with them.

How do I set the status of the authorised account?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is still relevant, and the current-status API is deprecated, but the line:

```
$xml = "<current-status>" . htmlspecialchars($status, ENT_NOQUOTES, "UTF-8") . "</current-status>";
```

needs to be changed to:

```
$xml = "" . htmlspecialchars($status, ENT_NOQUOTES, "UTF-8") . "";
```